# How can I turn my house into a Pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

I just want to know if its possible. I have only two in my general area and I would like too add some if possible. This is probably a really stupid question but i'm just curious.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike with the other game niantic released (Ingress) there is currently not a function built-in to suggest new pokestops.

Even if there was a way to suggest new pokestops, I am afraid 'your house' would not be a valid pokestop.

**EDIT:** Pokestops are 'mostly' the same locations as the portals in Ingress. Over the last years ingress has built up a lot of these portals. So I don't think they are going to accept any pokestop suggestions anytime soon.

Comment: AFAIK, using the Ingress Intel map (requires login IIRC), you can find all the pokestops at the same positions as the portals are.

Comment: It seems like the pokestops have a 'limit' by density. Which means that if in ingress there 5 portals very nearby, there may only be 3 pokestops in pokemon go.

Answer (score 1):

All of the current PokéStop and Gym locations are based on location data from Niantic's previous game, Ingress (they're using the same coordinates, names, and pictures) - the Pokémon locations are a *subset* of the Ingress portals (and they are theoretically all landmarks and/or spots of cultural significance and places where people congregate). If they wanted more locations, they would likely first use additional locations from Ingress. And Ingress is not currently accepting new locations (actually, I've heard they may be accepting some in a few places where they don't already have enough Portals). So the odds of getting your house turned into a PokéStop or Gym any time soon are vanishingly low.

If you want to see all the Ingress portals nearby, download the [Ingress app](https://ingress.com) (available for Android and iOS, it's free-to-play, and you really don't need to spend anything - highly recommended), register as an agent (player), and the you can visit the intel map at [ingress.com/intel](https://ingress.com/intel)  and look up your local area.